# Is there a way to close 1 of multiple open files in with statement to just write to a subset of them after a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, with-statement

I would like to read from one file and write to either of 2 files using the `with` statement and not both at the same time.

I am looking to do this with the `with` statement both to avoid not closing a file when I move code around and out of curiosity.

The code I have below is writing only to `out1File`. I would like to close `out1File` so as to just write to `out2File` but I am uncertain as to what happens if I do so as `with` is supposed to close files for me from what I understand.

Is it just better to go with different `open` and `close` statements?

```py
with open('input.txt', mode='r') as inputFile, \
     open('output1.txt', mode='w') as out1File,     \
     open('output2.txt', mode='w') as out2File:
    lines = inputFile.readlines()
    isInput1 = False
    isInput2 = False
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("out1"):
            isInput1 = True
            continue
        elif isInput1:
            out1File.write(line.replace(":", " "))
        elif line.startswith("out2"):
            isInput1 = False
            isInput2 = True
            continue
        elif isInput2:
            out2File.write(line.replace(":", " "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem came from the if structure.

As you sticked the `line.startswith("out2")` with the main if block and also not set `isInput2 = False` in the first block, it assumes that the line starts always with out1, because of the initial check of `isInput1` that'll result always as true.

What I did is that I grouped the checking conditions and completed variable swap.

Maybe my solution to this problem won't be **THE BEST** technique, but If you want to stick to your code structure, I guess this will work:

```
with open('input.txt', mode='r') as inputFile, \
 open('output1.txt', mode='w') as out1File,     \
 open('output2.txt', mode='w') as out2File:
lines = inputFile.readlines()
isInput1 = False
isInput2 = False
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("out1"):
        isInput1 = True
        isInput2 = False
        continue
    elif line.startswith("out2"):
        isInput2 = True
        isInput1 = False
        continue
    if isInput1:
        out1File.write(line.replace(":", " "))
    elif isInput2:
        out2File.write(line.replace(":", " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

A context manager is simply a class that runs an `.__enter__()` method and `.__exit__()` method. The exit method is automatically run even if their is an error, which is why it is used to close files after an error occurs. The built-in `open.__exit__()` looks something like:

```
def __exit__(*errors,**kerrors):
    self.close()
```

This means that open() runs .close() at the end of a "with statement" even if an error occurs during the "with statement". If you run, .close() inside the "with statement" that is equivalent to running .close() twice (once in the with statement and once when the with statement ends). Running .close() on an already closed file does nothing and shouldn't be an issue, so you can close your files during your with statement if you would like.